# Target a specific element with the same classes jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the code at a high level, and there are multiple such lists I have of the following structure:

```
<li class="wrap-input">
    <p>Some sentence</p>
    <select class="form-control">
      ...
    </select>
    <div class="button-in-input">
      ...
    </div>                                        
</li>
.
.
.
```

What I want to do is, whenever the user focuses on the "form-control" select, then the div with the "button-in-input" class should be shown, **but only in that particular li element**. i tried it with this jquery code:

```
$(".form-control").focusin(function() {
        $(".button-in-input").show();
    }).focusout(function() {
        $(".button-in-input").hide();
    });
```

But of course, this generalizes to all the li elements I have. I'm assuming there is a way to do it with the **this** keyword but note that the select and div elements are siblings.
Any help would be appreciated!

PS: I want to avoid using IDs otherwise there would be tons of repetetive code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with pure CSS.

```
.wrap-input .button-in-input {
    display: none;
}
.wrap-input select.form-control:focus + .button-in-input {
    disply: block;
}
```

The *select* in the second selector is not necessary, but it helps in case there's a different item with the same class.

Comment: So I'm adding an onClick event to the "button-in-input" element but with your code, what is happening is that right when I click the element, the input seems to go out of focus before the click event can be registered. Any idea how I could fix this?

Comment: As per you original code, when the select is in focus the input div is shown, and when the focus leaves the select, the input button is hidden. If you want the input button to remain visible even after the select is no longer in focus you should have stated that in your question. Right now we can't know this is your intent.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `:focus` in css to do it, no fancy javascript code needed for this

```css
.form-control:focus + .button-in-input {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: So I'm adding an onClick event to the "button-in-input" element but with your code, what is happening is that right when I click the element, the input seems to go out of focus before the click event can be registered. Any idea how I could fix this?